# Filter in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of elements in Javascript and I want to filter based on it's properties.

Now , the response object which I want to filter looks something like:

[image]

And the individual objects may have `row_stat_cd` either `"I"` or `"L"`.

I want to get only the `"I"` records. So I did ..

```
    referenceDataRecord.filter(isInactive);

    function isInactive(obj) {
        return obj.row_stat_cd != "L";
    };

    angular.forEach(referenceDataRecord, function (k, v) {
        .........
```

but still referenceDataRecord contains all the records . It is not being filtered and keeping only the `"I"` records.

Comment: `referenceDataRecord = referenceDataRecord.filter(isInactive);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` method by itself does not modify the array. You have to set reference to the variable

```
referenceDataRecord = referenceDataRecord.filter(isInactive);

    function isInactive(obj) {
        return obj.row_stat_cd != "L";
    };

    angular.forEach(referenceDataRecord, function (k, v) {
```

> The filter() method creates a **new array** with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.filter returns a new array with the filtered items. The original array is not changed unless you assign it to the output of the function like this.

`referenceDataRecord = referenceDataRecord.filter(isInactive);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter